# Reading a Vector from A file

Tags: java

I want to write a `Vector<Person>` into a file and then hopefully read it.

Writing in the file :

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("FileName"));
    Vector<Person> People = new Vector<Person>();
    People.addElement(new Person("first_name","last_name","address"));
    People.addElement(new Person("first_name2","last_name2","address"));

    oos.writeObject(People);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
```

Reading :

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("FileName"));

Vector<Person> P = (Vector<Person>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();

for(int i=0; i<P.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(P.elementAt(i).toString());
}
```

But is seems there is a problem in the casting... Can someone help ?! 
Thanks.

Comment: Vector was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998) Are you really sure you need to be using Vector?

Comment: No not really what ever gets the job done is fine by me ^^'

Comment: Start with `List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();` note the use of camelCase variable names. ;)

Comment: I replaced Vector with ArrayList but it did not really change anything Im still getting the same error.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:

Comment: The ClassCastException should tell you which class it thinks it should be. Can you try `List P = (List) ois.readObject();` and print the type of each element?

Comment: Thank you @PeterLawrey it's working :)